# How does the C++ compiler know which CPU architecture is being used

Tags: c++, assembly

with reference to : http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2v07M4Gy/

During the compilation phase,

This phase translates the program into a low level assembly level code. The compiler takes the preprocessed file ( without any directives) and generates an object file containing assembly level code. Now, the object file created is in the binary form. In the object file created, each line describes one low level machine level instruction.

Now, if I am correct then different CPU architectures works on different assembly languages/syntax.

**My question is how does the compiler comes to know to which assembly language syntax the source code has to be changed? In other words, how does the C++ compiler know which CPU architecture is there in the machine it is working on ?**

Is there any mapping used by assembler w.r.t the CPU architecture for generating assembly code for different CPU architectures?

N.S : I am beginner !!

Comment: Because the compiler has itself been built to target the explicit target architecture? Or if it supports multiple architecture, it knows the native architecture and uses that as default?

Comment: The name "architecture" already makes clear that there are more differences than just different assembly language.

Comment: unless you use a so called "Cross-compiler", most compilers are writing code for the OS they're running on

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each compiler needs to be "ported" to the given system. For each system supported, a "compiler port" needs to be programmed by someone who knows the system in-depth.

Comment: Ok. got it. Thanks. So, how this happens when we download dev C++, or turbo C++ setup files( for  windows).

Comment: @user7689322 Dev C++ used the Windows port of the gcc compiler, called "Mingw". Turbo C++ was a non-standard MS DOS compiler which doesn't work on Windows, because it was written for DOS. The only way to use it on Windows is to run it through an emulator.

Comment: Uh, Dev-C++ and Turbo C++ are incredibly old. There are far newer and better free C++ environments available. (Code::Blocks, QtCreator, Eclipse CDT, ...). Anyway, the answer is that the setup files of Dev-C++ include the MinGW32 GCC compiler, a version of GCC that is configured to produce code suitable for x86 chips running Windows.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I wouldn't call Eclipse better than anything. I've done projects in both Turbo C++ and Dev C++ (long time ago) where I was productive and focused on programming the application, rather than on configuring and debugging the IDE. Therefore, the Turbo C++ and Dev C++ IDE:s are superior to Eclipse, as is Codeblocks, QtCreator, notepad.exe...

Comment: @Lundin But at least Eclipse CDT supports modern compilers, unlike Dev-C++.

Comment: @user7689322 (only x86 world related) the modern x86 CPUs are backward compatible, as long as produced machine code does use only basic set of one generation of x86 instructions (80386 used to be the "work everywhere", nowadays often pentium/pentium_pro (586/686) are considered "safe to be everywhere"), it will work on new x86 CPU too (and the OS must support the same ABI the binary was created against). If extra instruction set like SSE2/AVX is used, then the executable has to check at runtime and have fallback implementation, or it will not work. But "does work" != "optimal machine code".

Comment: @user7689322 so if you download dev C++ from 80386 era, it will work, and it will produce 80386-like machine code, not using modern extensions, and being not optimal for current generation of x86 CPUs, but the produced machine code will still work well. Modern compilers often have several target architectures built inside them, with gcc you can pick if you want 386/586/686/SSE2/etc... in resulting binary, so you can hand-pick target architecture. Its support in the compiler had to be coded in by programmers first. You can select it by command line options.

Answer (score 5):

## WARNING : This is extremely simplified

In short, there are three main parts to a compiler :

- "Front-end" : This part reads the language (in this case c++) and converts it to a sort of pseudo-code specific to the compiler. (An Abstract Syntactic Tree, or AST)
- "Optimizer/Middle-end" : This part takes the AST and make a non-architecture-dependant optimized one.
- "Back-end" : This part takes the AST, and converts it to binary executable code, specific to the architecture you want to compile your language on.

When you download a c++ compiler for your platform, you, in fact, download the c++ frontend with the linux-amd64 backend, for example.

This coding architecture is extremely helpful, because it allows to port the compiler for another architecture without rewriting the whole parsing/optimizing thing. It also allows someone to create another optimizer, or even another frontend supporting a whole different language, and, as long as it outputs a correct AST, it will be compatible with every single backend ever written for this compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the knowledge of the target system is coded into the compiler.

So you might have a C compiler that generates SPARC binaries, and a C compiler that generates VAX binaries.  They both accept the same input language (as defined in the C standard), but produce different programs from it.

Often we just refer to "*the* compiler", meaning the one that will generate binaries for our current environment.

In modern times, the distinction has become less obvious with compiler collections such as GCC.  Now the "different compilers" are often the same compiler program, just set up with different configurations (these are the "target description files").

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the answers given here:

The target architecture is indeed coded into the specific compiler instance you're using. This is important also for a process called "cross-compiling" - The process of compiling on a certain system an executable that would operate on another system/architecture.

Consider working on an embedded system-on-chip that uses a completely different instruction set than your own - You're working on an x86/64 Linux system, but need to compile a mobile app running on an ARM micro-processor, or some other type of assembly architecture.
It would be unreasonable to compile your code on the target system, which might be so limited in CPU and memory that it can't feasibly run a compiler - and so you can use a GCC (or any other compiler) port for that target architecture on your favorite system.

It's also quite critical to remember that the entire tool-chain is often compatible to the target system, for instance when shared libraries such as libc are getting in play - as the target OS could be a different release of Linux and would have different versions of common functions - In which case it's common to use tool-chains that contain all the necessary libraries and use something like `chroot` or `mock` to compile in the "target environment" from within your system.